# Audit Alfresco Authority Deletion: no event is recorded

Tags: alfresco, audit

My goal is to audit deletion of authorities in Alfresco. When audit logging is enabled (which generates a *lot* of log entries), deleting a group results in these log entries (shortend):

```
/alfresco-api/pre/AuthorityService/deleteAuthority/args/name=GROUP_test_group_for_audit

/alfresco-node/beforeDeleteNode/node=workspace://SpacesStore/a4f5e9bb-6584-4997-a550-6080d0dce177

/alfresco-api/post/AuthorityService/deleteAuthority/args/name=GROUP_test_group_for_audit
/alfresco-api/post/AuthorityService/deleteAuthority/no-error=null
```

If I understand the documentation correctly, an audit XML file like this should record the first event:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>

<Audit
    xmlns="http://www.alfresco.org/repo/audit/model/3.2"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.alfresco.org/repo/audit/model/3.2 alfresco-audit-3.2.xsd"
    >

    <DataExtractors>
       <DataExtractor name="simpleValue" registeredName="auditModel.extractor.simpleValue"/>
    </DataExtractors>

        <DataGenerators>
           <DataGenerator name="currentUser" class="org.alfresco.repo.audit.generator.AuthenticatedUserDataGenerator"/>
           <DataGenerator name="personFullName" class="org.alfresco.repo.audit.generator.AuthenticatedPersonDataGenerator"/>
        </DataGenerators>

    <PathMappings>
        <PathMap source="/alfresco-api/pre/AuthorityService/deleteAuthority" target="/deleteAuthority"/>
    </PathMappings>

    <Application name="DeleteAuthority" key="deleteAuthority">
        <AuditPath key="deleteAuthority">
            <RecordValue key="name" dataExtractor="simpleValue" dataSource="/deleteAuthority/args/name"/>
        </AuditPath>
    </Application>

</Audit>
```

Note that in the `source` of the `PathMap` I use the path `/alfresco-api/pre/AuthorityService/deleteAuthority` as it appears in the first log entry. This looks correct to me, even though I am quite unsure how the `Application` element should look.

Putting this into the XML file `tomcat/shared/classes/alfresco/extension/audit/alfresco-audit-deleteAuthority-extractors.xml` registers the application correclty:

```
$ curl -u 'admin:secret' http://alfresco:8080/alfresco/service/api/audit/control
{
   "enabled" : true,
   "applications": 
   [
      {
         "name": "Alfresco Tagging Service",
         "path" : "/tagging",
         "enabled" : true
      }
         ,
      {
         "name": "DeleteAuthority",
         "path" : "/deleteAuthority",
         "enabled" : true
      }
         ,
      {
         "name": "alfresco-access",
         "path" : "/alfresco-access",
         "enabled" : true
      }

   ]
}
```

But when I now delete a group, nothing is recorded. A query for the application returns an empty result:

```
$ curl -u 'admin:secret' http://alfresco:8080/alfresco/service/api/audit/query/DeleteAuthority
{
   "count":0,
   "entries": 
   [
   ]
}
```

**Question:** Is my above audit application configuration correct? How would I have to change it to generate audit entries for the deletion of authorities?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your path-mapping section is correct, your application definition though is not set correctly to track the correct path.
You probably should try something like :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>

<Audit
    xmlns="http://www.alfresco.org/repo/audit/model/3.2"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.alfresco.org/repo/audit/model/3.2 alfresco-audit-3.2.xsd"
    >

    <DataExtractors>
       <DataExtractor name="simpleValue" registeredName="auditModel.extractor.simpleValue"/>
    </DataExtractors>

        <DataGenerators>
           <DataGenerator name="currentUser" registeredName="auditModel.generator.user"/>
        </DataGenerators>

    <PathMappings>
        <PathMap source="/alfresco-api/pre/AuthorityService/deleteAuthority" target="/deleteAuthority"/>
    </PathMappings>

    <Application name="DeleteAuthority" key="deleteAuthority">
        <AuditPath key="deleteAuthority">
            <RecordValue key="authority" dataExtractor="simpleValue" dataSource="/deleteAuthority/args/name" dataTrigger="/deleteAuthority/args/name"/>
            <GenerateValue key="deletingUser" dataGenerator="currentUser"/>
        </AuditPath>
    </Application>

</Audit>
```